# SQL - Comparing rows in table with lag function based on column values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a column named `previous_month` which based on the groups of distinct type/id looks to see for the previous row if `month_in` is one month less than the current row and if so `previous_month` = True and else False.

```
type    id  month_in    previous_month
a       1   2019-09-01  FALSE
a       1   2019-10-01  TRUE
a       1   2019-11-01  TRUE
a       1   2020-02-01  FALSE
a       2   2020-01-01  FALSE
a       2   2020-02-01  TRUE
```

I have tried using the lag function

```
Select 
       type, 
       id,
       month_for,
       lag(True, 1, False) over (partition by type, id order by type, id, month_for) as previous_month

from myTable
```

however, this doesn't account for when  `month_in` increases by more than one month, i.e. I get this table:

```
type    id  month_in    previous_month
a       1   2019-09-01  FALSE
a       1   2019-10-01  TRUE
a       1   2019-11-01  TRUE
a       1   2020-02-01  TRUE
a       2   2020-01-01  FALSE
a       2   2020-02-01  TRUE
```

Any suggestions on if this is possible with the lag function? or if not the most efficient way to achieve this? I am working in snowflake sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and you just need to make a slight change in your query to compare the difference in months. I am assuming as SQL server. You just need to make sure that the difference is previous and current row is within 1 month

```
Select 
       type, 
       id,
       month_for,
       case when datediff(month,  lag(month_for, 1) over (partition by type, id order by type, id, month_for), month_for) = 1 then 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' as previous_month

from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join and "not exists"

```
Select 
       a.type, 
       a.id,
       a.month_in,  
       case 
        when datediff(month, a.month_in, b.month_in)= -1 Then 'TRUE'
        else 'False' end as previous_month  

from myTable a left join myTable b on a.type = b.type and a.id = b.id and a.month_in > b.month_in
and not exists
(
  select 1 from myTable c where a.type = c.type and a.id = c.id
  and c.month_in > b.month_in and c.month_in < a.month_in 
)
```

Output:

```
type    id  month_in    previous_month
a   1   2019-09-01  False
a   1   2019-10-01  TRUE
a   1   2019-11-01  TRUE
a   1   2020-02-01  False
a   2   2020-01-01  False
a   2   2020-02-01  TRUE
```